# How to run iOS Simulator as iPhone 3GS non retina?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I upgraded to Xcode 5 and apparently the iOS Simulator doesn't support iPhone 3GS (i.e. iPhone non Retina 3.5-inch) anymore.

Is there any way I can run it?

I don't want to use an iPhone 3GS device and I want my game to support non retina devices.

Comment: The iPhone 4 is retina.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you change your target's iOS Deployment Target under Build Settings to iOS 6.0 or 6.1 the non-Retina iPhone Simulator option will become available. The iPhone 3GS runs ("at most") iOS 6.1 or lower, hence it does not appear in the list if the deployment target is iOS 7 or later.

Comment: Can this be done without creating an XCode project? (I'm designing a website, so I don't have an XCode project, but I do have XCode.)

Comment: If you launch the ios simulator you'll find somewhere in its menu are options to change the type of hardware being emulated. In order to see all options open xcode, go to xcode preferences and on the downloads tab check that the older ios simulator versions have been downloaded. Note that you may have to install older xcode versions if you want to test with older ios simulators, ie in xcode 5 the lowest available simulator is ios 5 i believe.

Answer (score 3):

It's the "iPhone 6.x" Simulator. You won't find a non-retina iPhone simulator for iOS 7 because no real iOS devices that are non-retina can run iOS 7.